# Incremental loading in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Given the following code:

```
listView.ItemsSource = 
App.azureClient.GetTable<SomeTable>().ToIncrementalLoadingCollection();
```

We get incremental loading without further changes.

But what if we modify the read.js server side script to e.g. use mssql to query another table instead. What happens to the incremental loading? I'm assuming it breaks; if so, what's needed to support it again?

And what if the query used the untyped version instead, e.g.

```
App.azureClient.GetTable("SomeTable").ReadAsync(...)
```

Could incremental loading be somehow supported in this case, or must it be done "by hand" somehow?

Bonus points for insights on how Azure Mobile Services implements incremental loading between the server and the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incremental loading collection works by sending the $top and $skip query parameters (those are also sent when you do a query by using the `.Take` and `.Skip` methods in the table). So if you want to modify the read script to do something other than the default behavior, while still maintaining the ability to use that table with an incremental loading collection, you need to take those values into account.

To do that, you can ask for the query *components*, which will contain the values, as shown below:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    var queryComponents = query.getComponents();
    console.log('query components: ', queryComponents); // useful to see all information
    var top = queryComponents.take;
    var skip = queryComponents.skip;
    // do whatever you want with those values, then call request.respond(...)
}
```

The way it's implemented at the client is by using a class which implements the [`ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading.aspx). You can see it (and the full source code for the client SDKs) in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services), or more specifically the [MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollection class](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WindowsStore/Collections/MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollection.cs) (the method is added as an extension in the [MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollectionExtensions class](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WindowsStore/Extensions/MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollectionExtensions.cs)).

And the untyped table does not have that method - as you can see in the extension class, it's only added to the typed version of the table.